# session variable removed from session after form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, cookies

I set a session var :time_block_id in show.
When the form is submitted, you see the same session_id and _csrf_token but the :time_block_id is gone. Any ideas?
Rails 3.2.6

controller.rb

```
def show
  session[:time_block_id] = "test"
  debugger
  (rdb:663) p session 
  # outputs ...
  {"session_id"=>"1232115b1ffe78b7e71163e4bd48974a", "user_return_to"=>"/app/admin/clients", "_csrf_token"=>"/aFAp07yrpQtjgXDS2HQk+uNZLD3QuGRzSGX4Mszyug=", "warden.user.user.key"=>["User", [2], "$2a$10$1Mn/Riq9WdmnUUUiVhXbsO"], "time_block_id"=>"test"}

  render_wizard
end

def update
  debugger
  (rdb:663) p session
{"session_id"=>"1232115b1ffe78b7e71163e4bd48974a", "user_return_to"=>"/app/admin/clients", "_csrf_token"=>"/aFAp07yrpQtjgXDS2HQk+uNZLD3QuGRzSGX4Mszyug=", "warden.user.user.key"=>["User", [2], "$2a$10$1Mn/Riq9WdmnUUUiVhXbsO"]}

  a = ""
end
```

_form.html.haml

```
=simple_form_for @time_block, url: wizard_path, :method => :put do |f|
    =f.submit "go"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to move the "time_block_id" variable before the "warden.user.user.key" and check also tour model.
It is more likely that an error on the previous parameter to block the rest of the process without an error message.